# Gradle for STS Eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, gradle-plugin

Need to install buildship or Gradle IDE 3.8.4.201703310540-RELEASE on STS based on eclipse Neon?
STS Info:

> Spring Tool Suite
>
> Version: 3.8.4.RELEASE Build Id: 201703310825 
>   Platform: Eclipse Neon.3
>   (4.6.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to *Help -> Install New Software... -> Add...*

In the *Location* field that appears, enter the following URL: `http://download.eclipse.org/buildship/updates/e46/releases/2.x`

Optionally fill in the *Name* field. You should have something similar to the following at this point:

[image: Buildship installation]

Click *OK*, tick the box that appears next to *Buildship: Eclipse Plug-ins for Gradle* and click *Next*. You can then follow the remaining steps to install the plugin, and restart Eclipse once everything is done.

Comment: Yes buildship was already there in the default list. Just wanted to know which to take?

Comment: Why not go for version 2.0.2? It's the latest release and is supposed to work fine on STS 3.8.4. ;-)